# Organizing site navigation actions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

I'm new to Rails (I've worked in MVC but not that much) and I'm trying to do things the "right" way but I'm a little confused here.

I have a site navigation with filters Items by different criteria, meaning:

```
Items.popular  
Items.recommended

User.items

Brand.items # by the parent brand

Category.items # by a category
```

The **problem** is that I don't know how to deal with this in the controller, where each action does a similar logic for each collection of items (for example, store in session and respond to js)

Either I have an action in `ItemsController` for every filter (big controller) *or* I put it in `ItemsController` `BrandsController`, `CategoriesController` (repeated logic), but neither provides a "clean" controller.

But I don't know witch one is better or if I should do something else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ideally you should handle this in items controller index action as you are applying filter on items

Comment: Take a look at http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model.

Comment: @Rubyman But how can I implement it? I can only think of many conditionales. At David Will do, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking two separate questions. `Items.popular` and `Items.recommended` are best achieved in your `Item` model as a [named scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) This abstracts what Xavier recommended into the model. Then in your `ItemsController`, you'd have something like

```
def popular
    @items = Item.popular
end

def recommended
    @items = Item.recommended
end
```

This isn't functionally different than what Xavier recommended, but to me, it is more understandable. (I always try to write my code for the version of me that will come to it in six months to not wonder what the guy clacking on the keyboard was thinking.)

The second thing you're asking is about [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). Assuming your code reads something like:

```
class User
    has_many :items
end
```

then you can route through a user to that user's items by including

```
resources :users do
    resources :items
end
```

in your routes.rb file. Repeat for the other nested resources.

The last thing you said is

> The problem is that I don't know how to deal with this in the controller, where each action does a similar logic for each collection of items (for example, store in session and respond to js)

If what I've said above doesn't solve this for you (I think it would unless there's a piece you've left out.) this sounds like a case for subclassing. Put the common code in the superclass, do the specific stuff in the subclass and call `super`.

Comment: This is probably what I'm looking for, but one last question, where should the nested resource action go? to a `user_items` action?

Comment: Read up on nested resource routes. By adding that to your routes, you'll get something like `http://mysite.com/users/[identifier]/items` and helpers like `user_items_url(@some_user_object)` to generate the URLs for you. There's no controller action required.

Comment: I ask because that means I have to know witch identifier to use ( for example `params[:user_id]` or `params[:category_id]` ) so I'll have a lot of `if` (I defenetly take a good read anyways, thank you)

Comment: Like I said, I could be missing some portion of the story. Yes, you will need the ItemsController to check for those parameters, but what is the alternative other than the scenario you asked help solving?

Comment: Sorry for not being consistent. Just meant that I'll have `Brands` and `Category` as showed in the question pointing to the same action, and I'll have to distinguish between the two identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty convenient way to handle this, actually - you just have to be careful and sanitize things, as it involves getting input from the browser pretty close to your database.  Basically, in `ItemsController`, you have a function that looks a lot like this:

```
def search
    @items = Item.where(params[:item_criteria])
end
```

Scary, no?  But effective!  For security, I recommend something like:

```
def search
    searchable_attrs = [...] #Possibly load this straight from the model
    conditions = params[:item_criteria].keep_if do |k, v|
        searchable_attrs.contains? k
    end
    conditions[:must_be_false] = false
    @items = Item.where(conditions)
end
```

Those first four lines used to be doable with ActiveSupport's [Hash#slice](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Slice) method, but that's been deprecated.  I assume there's a new version somewhere, since it's so useful, but I'm not sure what it is.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't dislike this idea, but I presented it to my coworker/boss and he got scared ^^

Comment: @Nico - Fair enough!  When I was doing this, we needed the ability to combine filters, and named scopes got a little unwieldy, but I like that jxpx's version pulls all the logic into the model.  I think you made the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

I think both answers(@Xaviers and @jxpx777's) is good but should be used in different situations. If your view is exactly the same for popular and recommended items then i think you should use the same action for them both. Especially if this is only a way to filter your index page, and you want a way to filter for both recommended and popular items at the same time. Or maybe popular items belonging to a specific users? However if the views are different then you should use different actions too.

The same applies to the nested resource (user's, brand's and category's items). So a complete index action could look something like this:

```
# Items controller
before_filter :parent_resource

def index
  if @parent
    @items = @parent.items
  else
    @items = Item.scoped
  end

  if params[:item_criteria]
    @items = @items.where(params[:item_criteria])
  end
end

private

def parent_resource
  @parent = if params[:user_id]
    User.find(params[:user_id])
  elsif params[:brand_id]
    Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
  elsif params[:category_id]
    Category.find(params[:category_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks a lot more like what I have right now. `parent_resource` was my concern because I don't have a lot of knowledge in Rails and those `if`s scared me.

Comment: Sure it's not too pretty, and maybe you should consider using a private method for searching to refactor it a bit. However the most common way to use nested resources is to show them on the parent show action. Eg showing a users items, on the show/profile page for that user.